# Swift Programming

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swift

I am beginner of swift language. I am getting this error:

```
Error: Any object does not have member named subscript.
```

Can any one give solution for this?

My code:

```
        controller! = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Hi...", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Please enter atleat 10 characters", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {[weak self] (paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in

            let userName = self!.controller!.textFields[0].text
            println("your username is \(userName)")
        })

        controller!.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField:UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "XXXXX-XXXXX"
        })
```

Comment: How did you declare the variable `textFields`?

Comment: Actually that code was in cook book . i jus typed it. i got that error.. can yu give a correct code for this??

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var controller = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome", message: "Hi...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Please enter atleat 10 characters", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {[weak self] (paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in

            var userName = controller.textFields?
            println("your username is \(userName)")
        })
        controller.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField:UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "XXXXX-XXXXX"
        })
        controller.view.center = self.view.center
        self.view .addSubview(controller.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {[weak self](paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in
                if let textFields = self!.controller?.textFields{
                let theTextFields = textFields as [UITextField]
                let userName = theTextFields[0].text
                println("Your username is \(userName)")
            }

        })
```